# does the limit product rule applies to $0$? can I apply the product rule with $c \to \infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Consider the limit product rule

$$\lim_{x \to c} (f(x)⋅g(x)) =[\lim_{x \to c} f(x)]\cdot[\lim_{x \to c} g(x)]$$

I have three questions,

1) can I apply this to $0$ as for example:

$h(x) = f(x) \cdot g(x)\\
g(x) = x\\
f(x) = 0$

$\lim_{x \to c} h(x) = \\
\lim_{x \to c} 0 \cdot g(x) = \\
\lim_{x \to c} 0 \cdot \lim_{x \to c} g(x)$

is it true?

2) can I apply this when $c \to \infty$ and $f(x) = 0$?

$\lim_{x \to \infty} h(x) = \\
\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \cdot \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = \\
\lim_{x \to \infty} 0 \cdot x \\
= 0 $

is it true?

3) taking $0$ as constant and the same situation as 2):

$0 \cdot \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)\\
= \lim_{x \to \infty} (0) \cdot \lim_{x \to \infty} x\\
= \lim_{x \to \infty} (0 \cdot x)\\
= 0$

is it true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you can't. The product rule for limits only applies if you do not reach an indeterminate form e.g. $0\times\infty$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If f is the zero function then so is h, and it is easy to take the limit directly and then check if that answer is the same as what you get when you apply this rule.

Comment: Yes, you can, provided that the two limits on the RHS exist (finitely).

Comment: I guess Simply Beautiful Art and Zach is right actually. you can only say that the limit is 0 if h(x) was 0 previously, however, if g(x) and f(x) only turned to be 0 so h(x) would supposedly be 0 after you applied the limits, then 0 * infinity is undetermined.
Please tell me if I said anything wrong, and thank you.

Comment: So long as the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)=0$ and $g(x)$ is bounded within the interval $(c-\epsilon,c+\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon>0$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to c}(f(x)g(x))=0$.  Similarly if $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$ and $g(x)$ is bounded to the right, then again $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(f(x)g(x))=0$.  By bounded to the right, I mean there exists some real $X$ and some real $N$ such that for all $x>X$ you have $|g(x)|\leq N$.  If $g$ is unbounded, then more care needs to be taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual variant of product rule of limits is as follows:

> **Product rule of limits**: If both $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) $ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) $ exist then $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) g(x) $ also exists and $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) g(x) =\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \cdot\lim_{x\to a} g(x) \tag{1}$$ The above statement holds if $a$ is replaced by symbols $\infty, - \infty$.

The main limitation of the rule is that it does not say anything about the cases when one or both of the limits $\lim_{x\to a} f(x), \lim_{x\to a} g(x) $ do not exist. Most limit questions tend to involve such cases.

A slight but very useful improvement over the above is that *the equation $(1)$ holds provided one of the limits of $f, g$ exists and* ***is non-zero***. If the limit of one of the functions is $0$ then one can not proceed without the knowledge of the limit of the other function.

From your wording of the question it appears that you also want to deal with the case when $f(x) =0$ identically. In this case the whole product is $0$ and the limit is also $0$.

Comment: thank you!, that solved my doubts

Answer (score 0):

You can take a limit but the answer will be undetermined (in situation $2$). you have $0\times \infty$, which means that you need different way to get the limit. The way you should think about it is just like you said at the start:$$\lim_{x \to c} (f(x)⋅g(x)) =[\lim_{x \to c} f(x)]\cdot[\lim_{x \to c} g(x)]$$and after doing this try to evaluate the answer. In the case where the answer is $0\times\infty$ now, $h(x)=f(x)\times g(x)= \frac{1}{\frac{1}{f(x)}}\times g(x)=\frac{g(x)}{\frac{1}{f(x)}}$, put $f(x)=0,g(x)=\infty$ as $x$ goes to some value(can be infinity) you will get $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ and now use L'hospital's rule and you will find the limit. As for case $3$, you can take the limit but there is no answer.